# On ARM why does signed char'nes cause the program to output garbage values using getc and puts?

Tags: c, x86, raspberry-pi, arm, portability

So I am implementing a singly linked list implementation in C. I originally wrote some of it on an x86 (MacBook Pro Retina, late 2015) running an Intel Haswell processor on OSX Sierra. The code below is a function that reads every character in a file, and outputs it to the user before returning it to the calling function as a pointer to an array on the heap.

```
char* read_file(void)
{
   char *buf = (char*) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
   FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
   if (fp == NULL) {
       puts("Could not open file!");
       exit(-1);
    }

   char c;
   int i;

   i = 0;
   while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && i <= 1024-1) {
        buf[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    buf[i] = 0;

    puts(buf);

    return buf;
}
```

(data.txt)

```
1 2 3 4 1 3 4
```

On x86 this gives the correct output, just data.txt. But on ARM (armv7), when I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g linked-list.c
```

I get: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N71LJ.png)

on x86 it simply outputs the correct numbers to the terminal.

On the ARM side I am using a raspberry pi 3, not overclocked or anything. It runs armv7.

Why does the code above not work on ARM?

I have a theory it might be because the C standard does not defined the signdness of chars. And as EOF is defined to be -1 on most systems the -1 is promoted to 0XFF, and thus never stops executing until the buffer limit is reached. Is that right??

Comment: `getc` returns an `int`.

Comment: @a3f yeah so there is some precision lost, and some signed lost if int is unsigned an char is signed or vice versa.

Comment: Aside `i <= 1024-1` ==> `i < 1024` a matter of style and readability.

Comment: @Lewis re the first comment, using `char` cannot distinguish `0xFF` from `EOF`.

Comment: @WeatherVane on ARM? Or on both systems?

Comment: On all systems. And `buf[i] = 0;` is writing out of the array bounds if the previous loop terminated by `i` limit. So the the code has *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh ok, I didn't spot that, thanks. I'll fix it.

Comment: I thought that the exact integer type of a "char" could be signed or unsigned and was compiler dependent. If you want a definitely signed character type you need to say "signed char". ARM compilers I'm most familiar with treat ordinary "char" variables as unsigned.

Comment: @andymango yeah as far as I understand the C standard does not specify whether char is signed or unsigned, but most systems have signed chars because ASCII only needs 128 different values or so, so chars can be negative if two's complement is used! Yeah if I have give the flag -fsigned-char the code works. No idea why ARM chose to use unsigned chars, weird.